# How to maintain public and private connectionStrings config settings?

Tags: .net, web-config, connection-string

With the appSettings, you can specify an external file and then it will merge/override your settings. This is great if you have, for example, creds to a sandbox in the file that gets checked into source control, but you can also point to a local file with creds to a live server when needed that will override the setting in your web.config and this way you don't have to constantly exclude your web.config from check ins (or accidentally check in production creds as I've certainly done in the past).

Unfortunately, this isn't possible with the configSource attribute that is used to specify an external file for other sections such as the connectionStrings section.

So my question is, is there a simple way to achieve the behavior I'm wanting with the connectionStrings settings? I mean, I know I can write some custom code to accomplish this in some fashion but I just want to check that there isn't an out of the box solution I'm overlooking first.

Comment: Can't you just use configSource to reference a file that's checked in to source control (with sandbox creds), then overwrite the file when deploying to production.

Comment: @Joe Yes, but that's not the issue. I need to run the application in development pointed to staging and/or production from time to time. When I do this I temporarily modify the web.config and just exclude it from being checked in. Instead, I would like to override the connection strings with settings from a file that does not get checked in (i.e. is not even in source control). Or some similar solution I haven't thought of that effectively accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: How about this: configSource references a file that is excluded from source control.  You can edit this file to point to your different environments. Also you could have a post-build event that generates the file with default (sandbox) credentials if it doesn't already exist: this covers the case where a new developer gets the project from source control and therefore doesn't have the file on his local disk.

Comment: @Joe Hmm... so how would I do that? Off the top of my head I'm thinking I check in a file, say defaultConnections.config with default values. Then have a post build copy command that copies it to connections.config (the real one referenced by web.config) only if it doesn't already exist. Does that sound about right, or did you have anything simpler in mind?

Comment: That sounds good to me.